# How to get the full text file after merge?

Tags: python-3.x, merge

I’m merging two text files `file1.tbl` and `file2.tbl` with a common column. I used pandas to make data frames of each and merge function to have the output.

The problem is the output file does not show me the whole data and there  is a row of "..." instead and at the end it just prints [9997 rows x 5 columns].

I need a file containing the whole 9997 rows.

```py
import pandas

with open("file1.tbl") as file: 
   d1 = file.read()
with open("file2.tbl") as file: 
   d2 = file.read()

df1 = pandas.read_table('file1.tbl', delim_whitespace=True, names=('ID', 'chromosome', 'strand'))
df2 = pandas.read_table('file2.tbl', delim_whitespace=True, names=('ID', 'NUClen', 'GCpct'))
merged_table = pandas.merge(df1, df2)

with open('merged_table.tbl', 'w') as f:
    print(merged_table, file=f)
```

Comment: I would recommend not using print for this; look at pandas docs for the opposite of read_table.

Comment: by default pandas merge uses an inner join [pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)
try: `pandas.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on='ID')`
and as @jonrsharpe mentioned: pandas offers some write methods. e.g. pd.Dataframe.to_csv()